# Can someone explain C# static variables usage to me, when accessing from another script?

Tags: c#

Keep in mind I'm new to C#. Static variables don't seem to serve the same purpose as in C/C++, Fortran, etc. so I'm struggling a bit, esp. with this:

I want to be able to attach game objects to variables using the inspector, but access those variables (say, the color of Text UIs) from another script, without hard-coding object names (which could change) and using Find/GetComponent.

If I make the game objects static, I can access them instead with a statement like classname.objectname. However, the inspector no longer sees those variables (since they're static?), and so I can no longer attach a game object to them using inspector, so I'm back to using GameObject.Find or GetComponent and hard-coding the names somewhere in my code. Hopefully, I'm just ignorant about something, hence my question.

So: how can I declare a variable to which I can attach an object in the inspector (and avoid hard-coding the object name), yet access it in a different script without using Find/GetComponent?

Comment: _I want to be able to attach game objects to variables using the inspector_ I'm guessing this is referring to a game engine, probably unity, right? If so, you should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: What means: script? Do not name the C# source as script - this is not PHP!

Comment: The question is not a general question about `C#`, but rather about the specific data visibility on something called the `inspector`. If you are looking for an example of when to use `static` look no further than singletons, where a single `readonly static` field is needed. This is the recommended use of `System.Random` for example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I omitted the Unity tag. 

Unity refers to C# files as scripts, as do a lot of documents at learn.microsoft.com.

I'm not familiar with singletons. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Static is generally a bad idea. Statics are global. And pretty much the week after we invented and published the concept of globals, we realized it was a terrible idea. Particular statics should never be used for sharing data.

The only thing "special" in regards to C#/.NET is that it is what I call "stricly OOP". Everything must be part of a class, including static fields. There is no "standalone" variables of functions like I remember them from Native C++.

You should only use static classes and static fields for stuff that is extremly constant. Stuff like Function Collection Classes (see [Math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math)), (compile time) `constants` and `readonly` (runtime constants). But personally I even consider the Math class to be a fringe case/counter example. It just **happened** to work out with that class. It could have easily backfired.

A class that needs instantiation assigned to a static variable. And the above two types of constants. That is about the closest I ever got to using static in any context.

Comment: `static` exists for a reason. It´s neither generally good nor bad. It depends on how you use it.

Comment: Furthermore `readonly` and `static` are complete unrelated. You can of course also have non-static `readonly`-fields.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Statics suffered and still suffers from the same issues Threads faced: They were used for cases they were not intended for and cases they were not the right solution for - simply because they were the best low-code solution around at the time.| I also only compared readonly to constant. One is a rumtime the other a compile time constant. And constants are the one case where static (implicitly or explicitly) is generally a good idea.